# Beginning Android 4.0 Application Development by Wei-Meng Lee Eclipse Version Error

Tags: android, eclipse

I am a android beginner. I am going through the book listed in the title. I haven't even made it past the first chapter without running into problems. I have installed the latest version of Eclipse. However, the examples shown in the book are not much like my version. For instance, this main.xml file that's supposed to be in the layout folder is not there. The "New Android Project" dialog box is arranged very differently and the package explorer is called project explorer. Is there a way to get this kind of eclipse in the book? Or do I just have to interpret it best I can? Any help would be much appreciated! This question has been down voted and closed by another user. Could someone please tell me why? I am just trying to get some help.

Comment: The reason this question keeps getting downvoted is because it's not a software question, but more of an application question. Stackoverflow is specifically for software related question. This isn't.

Comment: Correction: It is neither app nor software related. It is programming related! For software, you should go to superusers, for example.

Comment: The answer from @RobAveryIV is probably the best you are going to get. You are, basically, going to have to interpret things as best you can and accept that various things will change in Android and also with the ADT plugin for Eclipse. You've already worked out that Package Explorer is now Project Explorer and as for `main.xml` it is now `activity_main.xml`. If you really want the kind of IDE in the book, check which version the author used - the older versions of Eclipse and ADT should be available for download although I'd recommend you stick with what is current.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Thank you! I knew my comment didn't sound right.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know not to ask those certain question. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As different Android APIs(ICS, JB, etc.) are released, they sometimes change the ADT (Android Development Tools) for Eclipse. The ADT is plugin for Eclipse. This plugin is what gives you all those neat buttons in the toolbar and the XML layout interaction.

The book you are reading was designed for Android 4.0(Ice Cream Sandwhich). As of right now, Google has released up to Android 4.2.2(JB 4.2). There has been some significant changes to the ADT going from ICS to JB, but in my opinion, they are for the good. Lots of really neat and new features. Here is a Google resource explaining the different API releases for Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

I would say continue reading the book as it will teachs you the basics of Android, but when you want to do some in depth coding, that book isn't going to be very useful and you may have to do a little research online. Reason is, Google releases at least two new versions of Android every year. Every version changes, and adds new features. In other words, the book you are reading is already out of date. Android OS development moves way to fast for authors to keep updating their books.

To answer your question, your probably going to have to interpret it the best you can since, most likely, by June/July, Key Lime Pie is going to out, and the ADT your using NOW will be outdated. You should really learn the fundamentals of Android OS and how it works in the background and how processes things. After that, everything else should be easier to learn.

An alternative to the book you are reading is this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html. This is straight from Google and is constantly updated and tweeked. This will be the most updated and useful information on how to write Android apps.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found that the best answer for this was on the actual Wrox forum for this book. Thanks for your time!